# How do you specify where to start reading in a file when using StreamReader?

Tags: c#, streamreader

How do you specify where to start reading in a file when using StreamReader?

I have created a streamreader object, along with a file stream object. After both objects are created, how would I go upon controlling where I want the StreamReader to start reading from a file?

Let's say the file's contents are as follows,

```
// song list.
// junk info.
1. Song Name
2. Song Name
3. Song Name
4. Song Name
5. Song Name
6. Song Name
```

How would I control the streamreader to read from let's say #2? Also, how could I also control where to make it stop reading by a similar delimiter like at #5?

Edit: By delimiter I mean, a way to make StreamReader start reading from ('2.')

Comment: If you want to ignore lines marked as comments, it's much easier to read them normally and then filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to deserialize a file into some in-memory object? If so, you may want to simply parse the entire file in using `ReadLine` or something similar, store each line, and then access it via a data structure such as a `KeyValuePair<int, string>`.

Update: Ok... With the new info, I think you have two options. If you're looking at reading until you find a match, you can `Peek()`, check to see if the character is the one you're looking for, and then `Read()`. Alternatively, if you're looking for a set position, you can simply `Read()` that many characters and throw away the return value.

If you're looking for complex delimiter, you can read the entire line or even the entire file into memory and use [Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30wbz966.aspx).

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 1):

If the file contains new line delimiters you can use [ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx) to read a line at a time.

So to start reading at line #2, you would read the first line and discard and then read lines until line #5.

Answer (score 0):

Well if the content is just plain text like that, you should use the StreamReader's ReadLine method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx

-Oisin